# Как добавить фрагмент на Bottom-Sheet?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-dialog, bottom-sheet

Я хочу реализовать фрагмент, который будет находится поверх Bottom-Sheet. Но моя проблема, заключается в том, что фрагмент находится сзади Bottom-Sheet.
Bottom-Sheet реализован во фрагменте.

> Вот код вызова фрагмента:

```
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                AimsMetkaIconsFragment newFragment = new AimsMetkaIconsFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                transaction.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно что и куда вам нужно положить. Учитывайте что куда вы кладёте: `transaction.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();`
 "`content`" - здесь выступает в роли контейнера, где он у вас будит и какой формы, такой вы и получите свой фрагмент.